# On a client app, what is the best way to monitor JBoss accessibility and DB accessibility

Tags: java, database, jboss, database-connection, jboss6.x

I have a client application connected to a JBoss server connected to a postgreSQL database server. Very basic stuff!

We want to monitor the connections between client<->server and server<->database and inform the user whenever they drop.

What is the best practice to monitor the connection to JBoss?

- deploy an EJB and make clients use it periodically
- ping
- use a TCP socket
- some application server service I don't know about...

And what is the best practice to monitor the connection to the database knowing that the database server might not even be accessible from the client application?

- Notify clients through a JMS topic
- Notify clents through a socket message
- Deploy an EJB and make clients call it periodically
- some application server service I don't know about...

**For all the solutions I can think of, I'd need JBoss to detect database failures and I don't know how to do that!**